# Connect to two different networks, simultaneously, with Ubuntu host and Ubuntu guest - Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

Using Ubuntu as a host and also as a guest on Virtualbox.
Can someone explain how to connect both host and guest, simultaneously, to different wireless networks, with the very same wireless network device.

If it is not possible with the same wireless network device, I would can use the usb dongle from a wireless keyboard.

Or, if it is not really possible to work one of the above, I would be interest to use the Ethernet cable for the host and wifi connection for the guest.

In the last instance, the most unhappy possibility, to use the Ethernet cable for the guest, and the wireless connection for the host. Best regards.

Comment: Can I confirm your objective? You want to have both the host and guest OSes use the very same wireless network device to connect to two different WiFi networks simultaneously?

Comment: Indeed, yes, please, @Matigo Thank you. Best wishes.

Comment: It is not possible to do this with most systems because devices generally have just one wireless interface. What you could do is to get a second WiFi device and dedicate the two to different networks on the host, bridging them with the VM.

Comment: Thank you @Matigo. If it is not possible with the same wireless network device, I would can use the usb dongle from a wireless keyboard.

Or, if it is not really possible to work one of the above, I would be interest to use the Ethernet cable for the host and wifi connection for the guest.

In the last instance, the most unhappy possibility, to use the Ethernet cable for the guest, and the wireless connection for the host. Best regards.